# Gitlab CI_JOB_TOKEN permissions to read package registry of other project

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to use Gitlab as my new private npm package registry.
I can publish my npm package (a library) to the projects registry using the CI_JOB_TOKEN.
The problem: I can't read that package using npm ic in a Gitlab ci job of another project.

The hierarchy of groups/sub-groups/projects is

- group/

  - lib-project
  - apps/

    - app-project

The error in the app-projects ci job is

```
   npm ERR! code E404
   npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://my.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/npm/@group%2flib-project
   npm ERR! 404 
   npm ERR! 404  '@group/lib-project@^1.0.1' is not in this registry.
```

When I try the URL `https://my.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/npm/@group%2flib-project` in my browser (logged in as the owner of those projects) I get info about the package, so the package is there.

When I try the same URL without being logged in I get `{"message":"404 Project Not Found"}`

**So it seems it is a problem with the CI_JOB_TOKEN not having the permission to read from another project** but it seems pretty common to use one GitLab project as registry (used by other projects). And it seems to be ok to use the CI_JOB_TOKEN to authenticate regarding to [the GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/workflows/project_registry.html#store-different-package-types-in-one-gitlab-project). Any hint what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My CI_JOB_TOKEN does have the right permissions. The problem was a copy/paste error in my `.gitlab-ci.yml` and therefore in my npm config:

```
echo "@scope:registry=https://my.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/npm/">>.npmrc
echo "//${CI_SERVER_HOST}/api/v4/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}">>.npmrc
```

The first (hardcoded) path to the registry is right but the second line is evaluated to a different path. Of course the ${CI_PROJECT_ID} contains the project-id of the app project when I build the app. The library package is published to the library project (the hardcoded project-id / 6 in the first line).

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the GitLab npm registry for the `@group` namespace using a .npmrc file:

```
@group:registry=https://my.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/npm/
//my.gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/npm/:_authToken=${CI_JOB_TOKEN}
```

To avoid hard-coding the `authToken` value in the file, you can use the npm config set command to add the token to the file:

```
npm config set -- '//gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/6/packages/npm/:_authToken' "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}
```

Comment: I already did it the way you explain it. Nevertheless, you pointed me in the right direction! I wanted to append my two .npmrc lines to my question above and saw the problem...see my answer. Thanks a lot!